# how to select input in datatable using jquery

Tags: jquery, select, datatable, field, using

I am generating row in datatable using create row function and I want to select `add_quantity` field and `price_input` field and do some calculation and show them in a `total_price` field of each row in DataTable

I'm doing something like this but all i can get the only first row field rest of row is still uncalculated

This is how I created row into `cart_table`

```
var t = $('#cart_table').DataTable();

            // $('#add-to-cart_table').on( 'click','.btn-cart', function () {
                t.row.add( [
                    $(this).data('id'),
                    $(this).data('name'),
                    (`<input type="text" id="add_qty" class="prdt-qty" style="width:30px">`),
                    (`  
                        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                            <label class="form-check-label">
                                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" checked id="price_checkbox"> 
                            </label>
                            <input type="text" id="price_input" value= "`+$(this).data('by_p') +`" class="disable-form">
                        </div>
                    `),
                    (`<input type="text" disabled id="total_price" class="prdt-qty" style="width:30px">`),
                    ('<a href="#" class="btn btn-xs btn-delete"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a>')
                ] ).draw( false );
```

and this is how i select row field to calculate

```
$('#cart_table').on('click', 'tr', function () {
    var table = $('#cart_table').DataTable();

    var data = table.row(this);
    var qty = $('#add_qty').val();
    var price = $('#price_input').val();
    $('#add_qty').on('keyup',function(){
        qty = $(this).val();
        if(qty >=1 ){
            $('#total_price').val(qty*price);
        }
        else{
            $('#total_price').val(qty);
        }
        console.log(qty);
        console.log(price);
    })
        console.log(data);

} );
```

Answer (score 0):

because you use same id on multiple element. id is unique, dont use same id on multiple element. you can use class instead.

$('#price_input') => only return 1st element with id = price_input
$('.price_input') => return all element with class=price_input

but we can hack this using $('input[id="price_input"]') => return all element with attribute id=price_input

```
$('#cart_table').on('keyup', 'input[id="add_qty"]', function () {
    var tr= $(this).find('tr');
    var qty = $(this).val();
    var price = tr.find('#price_input').val();

        if(qty >=1 ){
            tr.find('input[id="total_price"]').val(qty*price);
        }
        else{
            tr.find('input[id="total_price"]').val(qty);
        }
        console.log(qty);
        console.log(price);

});
```

Comment: not working, I want to get value of selected row input field and then do some calculation and return